# See unmatched countries for joinCountryData2Map in rworldmap?

Tags: r, rworldmap

I'm using the `joinCountryData2Map` function in `rworldmap` to match my data to the countries in the world map.

I get this result:

```
230 codes from your data successfully matched countries in the map
11 codes from your data failed to match with a country code in the map
11 codes from the map weren't represented in your data
```

I cannot figure out how to view those two lists of 11 countries. I am guessing that those 11 countries have issues with their ISO2 codes that I need to correct, but am not sure which ones to check without being able to view those two lists.

I'm guessing there's a solution along the lines of just `View(SomeObject$Countries)` but I haven't been able to find anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `joinCountryData2Map(...,verbose=TRUE)` to print the names of the countries that failed to match in the console.

[From the FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rworldmap/vignettes/rworldmapFAQ.pdf): "You can see that a summary of how many countries are successfully joined is output to the console. You can specify verbose=TRUE to get a full list of countries"

```
library(rworldmap)

data(countryExData)

# Set Angola to fail
countryExData[countryExData$ISO3V10 == "AGO", "ISO3V10"] <- "AGO_FAIL"

# Attempt to join
# With verbose=TRUE, failed joins (ie Angola) are printed in the console
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(
  countryExData[,c("ISO3V10", "Country")],
  joinCode = "ISO3",
  nameJoinColumn = "ISO3V10",
  verbose = TRUE)

# > 148 codes from your data successfully matched countries in the map
# > 1 codes from your data failed to match with a country code in the map
# >      failedCodes failedCountries
# > [1,] "AGO_FAIL"  "Angola"       
# > 95 codes from the map weren't represented in your data
```

---

But what if you want to get the information on failed joins programmatically? I may have missed something, but I don't see an option for that (i.e., `str(sPDF)` or function arguments). However, looking at the internals of `joinCountryData2Map()`, the object `failedCountries` contains the info you want, so it should be easy enough to include it in the returned object.

Here's how you could modify `joinCountryData2Map()` to return a list with two elements: the first element is the default object, and the second element is `failedCountries`.

```
# Modify the function to return the failed joins in the environment
joinCountryData2Map_wfails <- function(
  dF, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "ISO3V10",
  nameCountryColumn = "Country", suggestForFailedCodes = FALSE, 
  mapResolution = "coarse", projection = NA, verbose = FALSE) {
  
  # Retain successful join as first element and failed join as second element
  ll <- list() # MODIFIED
  mapWithData <- getMap(resolution = mapResolution)
  if (!is.na(projection)) 
    warning("the projection argument has been deprecated, returning Lat Lon, use spTransform from package rgdal as shown in help details or the FAQ")
  listJoinCodesNew <- c("ISO_A2", "ISO_A3", "FIPS_10_", 
                        "ADMIN", "ISO_N3")
  listJoinCodesOld <- c("ISO2", "ISO3", "FIPS", 
                        "NAME", "UN")
  listJoinCodes <- c(listJoinCodesOld, listJoinCodesNew)
  if (joinCode %in% listJoinCodes == FALSE) {
    stop("your joinCode (", joinCode, ") in joinCountryData2Map() is not one of those supported. Options are :", 
         paste(listJoinCodes, ""), "\n")
    return(FALSE)
  }
  joinCodeOld <- joinCode
  if (joinCode %in% listJoinCodesOld) {
    joinCode <- listJoinCodesNew[match(joinCode, listJoinCodesOld)]
  }
  if (is.na(match(nameJoinColumn, names(dF)))) {
    stop("your chosen nameJoinColumn :'", nameJoinColumn, 
         "' seems not to exist in your data, columns = ", 
         paste(names(dF), ""))
    return(FALSE)
  }
  dF[[joinCode]] <- as.character(dF[[nameJoinColumn]])
  dF[[joinCode]] <- gsub("[[:space:]]*$", "", dF[[joinCode]])
  if (joinCode == "ADMIN") {
    dF$ISO3 <- NA
    for (i in 1:nrow(dF)) dF$ISO3[i] = rwmGetISO3(dF[[joinCode]][i])
    joinCode = "ISO3"
    nameCountryColumn = nameJoinColumn
  }
  matchPosnsInLookup <- match(as.character(dF[[joinCode]]), 
                              as.character(mapWithData@data[[joinCode]]))
  failedCodes <- dF[[joinCode]][is.na(matchPosnsInLookup)]
  numFailedCodes <- length(failedCodes)
  numMatchedCountries <- nrow(dF) - numFailedCodes
  cat(numMatchedCountries, "codes from your data successfully matched countries in the map\n")
  failedCountries <- dF[[nameCountryColumn]][is.na(matchPosnsInLookup)]
  failedCountries <- cbind(failedCodes, failedCountries = as.character(failedCountries))
  cat(numFailedCodes, "codes from your data failed to match with a country code in the map\n")
  if (verbose) 
    print(failedCountries)
  matchPosnsInUserData <- match(as.character(mapWithData@data[[joinCode]]), 
                                as.character(dF[[joinCode]]))
  codesMissingFromUserData <- as.character(mapWithData@data[[joinCode]][is.na(matchPosnsInUserData)])
  countriesMissingFromUserData <- as.character(mapWithData@data[["NAME"]][is.na(matchPosnsInUserData)])
  numMissingCodes <- length(codesMissingFromUserData)
  cat(numMissingCodes, "codes from the map weren't represented in your data\n")
  mapWithData@data <- cbind(mapWithData@data, dF[matchPosnsInUserData, 
  ])
  invisible(mapWithData)
  
  ll[[1]] <- mapWithData # MODIFIED
  ll[[2]] <- failedCountries # MODIFIED
  return(ll) # MODIFIED
}
```

---

Usage:

```
sPDF_wfails <- joinCountryData2Map_wfails(
  countryExData[,c("ISO3V10", "Country")],
  joinCode = "ISO3",
  nameJoinColumn = "ISO3V10",
  verbose = TRUE)

# This is the result of the original function
# sPDF_wfails[[1]]

# This is info on the failed joins
sPDF_wfails[[2]]

# >     failedCodes failedCountries
# > [1,] "AGO_FAIL"  "Angola"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that.